# delete certain columns of matrix when number of zero elements exceeds threshold avoiding loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a quite big `(107 x n)` matrix `X`. Within these `n` columns, each `three` columns belong to each other. So, the `first three` columns of matrix `X` build a block, then columns `4,5,6` and so on.

Within each block, the `first 100` row elements of the `first` column are important `X(1:100,1:3:end)`. Whenever in this first column the number of `zeros` or `NaNs` is greater or equal `20`, it should delete the whole block.

Is there a way to do this without a loop?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of columns of the input to be a multiple of `3`, there could be two approaches here.

**Approach #1**

```
%// parameters
rl = 100; %// row limit 
cl = 20; %// count limit

X1 = X(1:rl,1:3:end) %// Important elements from input
match_mat = isnan(X1) | X1==0 %// binary array of matches
match_blk_id = find(sum(match_mat)>=cl) %// blocks that satisfy requirements
match_colstart = (match_blk_id-1).*3+1 %// start column indices that satisfy
all_col_ind = bsxfun(@plus,match_colstart,[0:2]') %//'columns indices to be removed
X(:,all_col_ind)=[] %// final output after removing to be removed columns
```

Or if you prefer "compact" codes -

```
X1 = X(1:rl,1:3:end);
X(:,bsxfun(@plus,(find(sum(isnan(X1) | X1==0)>=cl)-1).*3+1,[0:2]'))=[];
```

---

**Approach #2**

```
X1 = X(1:rl,1:3:end)
match_mat = isnan(X1) | X1==0 %// binary array of matches
X(:,repmat(sum(match_mat)>=cl,[3 1]))=[] %// Find matching blocks, replicate to
                            %// next two columns and remove them from X
```

---

Note: If `X` is not a multiple of `3`, use this before using the codes - `X = [X zeros(size(X,1) ,3 - mod(size(X,2),3))]`.

Comment: If X is not a multiple of `3`, pad with zeros - `X = [X zeros(size(X,1) ,3 - mod(size(X,2),3))]` and then use this solution.

Comment: thanks you very much divakar! at a first glance it seems to solve the problem, at least it truncates the X matrix correctly. now it is up to me to understand how you solved it :-) p.s. n is a multiple of three

Comment: @rookieMI Use a small input and get the outputs from each step and analyze them. The little comments must help too! :)

Comment: @rookieMI Check out approach #2 too!

Comment: even more elegant :-)

Comment: Very nice. For approach #2 you can use also `X(:,kron(sum(match_mat)>=cl,[1 1 1]))=[];`

Comment: @Adiel Very nice alternative solution! Thank you, OP might find this useful too.